# Como pegar este valor dentro da <div>

Tags: tampermonkey

A div é está:

```
<div class="table_box br_0_0_5_5 user_points" style="border-top:none;">4,660</div>
```

Código para pegar está div:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("table_box br_0_0_5_5 user_points")[0]
```

Como posso obter o valor "4,660" e colocar em um alert? Tentei várias formas mas não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar `.textContent` (captura o texto dentro do elemento):

```js
var texto = document.getElementsByClassName("table_box br_0_0_5_5 user_points")[0].textContent;
alert(texto);
```

```html
<div class="table_box br_0_0_5_5 user_points" style="border-top:none;">4,660</div>
```

Mas você também não precisa incluir todas as classes no método, com apenas uma já pode ser suficiente (se ela for a primeira da página):

```js
var texto = document.getElementsByClassName("br_0_0_5_5")[0].textContent;
alert(texto);
```

```html
<div class="table_box br_0_0_5_5 user_points" style="border-top:none;">4,660</div>
```

Comment: Mais uma pergunta, se eu querer fazer um if com esse valor, dizendo que se ele for maior ou igual a 4,660 ele mostra o alert, como posso fazer isto? Obrigado

Comment: Pode fazer desta forma: `var texto = document.getElementsByClassName("br_0_0_5_5")[0].textContent;
var valor = parseFloat(texto.replace(",",""));
console.log(valor);
if(valor >= 4660){
   alert(texto);
}`